# Recovering White noise from the Brownian Sheet. A question concerning the notes on SPDE's from Walsh.

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-pde

In page 6  from the notes ["An introduction to SPDE's"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0074917) from Walsh, one reads:

[image]

The Brownian Sheet, is defined as follows:

[image]

The notation $((u,v), (s,t)]$ is a bit unclear also to me, and maybe it is the cause of my confusion.

In $\Bbb{R}^2$, $(0, (s,t)] = (0,s] \times (0,t]$ one might extend this definition to include more base point other than 0. In this spirit one can define for $u \leq s$, $v \leq t$
$$((u,v),(s,t)] = (u,s] \times (v,t].$$

That using this definition one then notes that 
$$(u,s] \times (v,t] = (0,s] \times (0,t] \setminus ((0,s] \times (0,v] \setminus \bigg( (0,u] \times (0,t] \setminus (0,u] \times (0,v])\bigg)$$

Here is a picture:

[image]

The above translates as

$$ 1 = 1234 - 34 - (24 - 4)  = 1234 -23 -4 $$

One should then have

$$W((u,s] \times (v,t]) = W_{st}- W_{sv} - (W_{ut} - W_{uv}) = W_{st}- W_{sv} - W_{ut} + W_{uv} $$

But that is not what is written. Is this a typo?